# Time difference since previous record in time series aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of events made by different actors. I now need to calculate the amount of events per actor that occurred x amount of time since the last time an event occurred.

A more concrete example: a collection of login events made by different actors. Every login event that happened less than 8 hours since the previous login should be ignored. So let's say I log in at 2pm and again at 11pm, the count we want would be 2. If I would log in at 2pm and again at 5pm, that would have to count for 1.

I don't really see a viable solution to this problem using the aggregation framework. A possible solution would be to calculate (and save) the time between te previous event for each record. But I feel there should be a better solution.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Didn't really find any usecases that are similar to this one.

If my question isn't clear, let me know!

---

**Edit:**

An example:

Simplified events:

```
[{
    _id: 1,
    actor: X,
    date: ISODate("2018-09-20T18:00:00.000Z")
},
{
    _id: 2,
    actor: X,
    date: ISODate("2018-09-21T05:00:00.000Z") // 11 hours since previous
},
{
    _id: 3,
    actor: X,
    date: ISODate("2018-09-21T07:00:00.000Z") // 2 hours since previous
},
{
    _id: 4,
    actor: Y,
    date: ISODate("2018-09-21T06:00:00.000Z")
},
{
    _id: 5,
    actor: Y,
    date: ISODate("2018-09-21T09:00:00.000Z") // 3 hours since previous
}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{
    _id: X,
    count: 2 // 3 events, but one is less than 8 hours since previous
},
{
    _id: Y,
    count: 1 // 2 events, but one is less than 8 hours since previous
}]
```

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected output?

Comment: @Akrion, added a simplified example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare values from different documents by grouping them into array and iterating over it. In your case [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) is probably the simplest way:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // ensure order
  { $sort: { date: 1 } }, 
  // get all dates per actor
  { $group: { _id: "$actor", dates: { $push: "$date" } } }, 
  { $addFields: {
      // iterate dates
      events: { $reduce: {
          input: "$dates",
          initialValue: { last: null, count: 1 },
          // increment counter if difference is > than 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000 millis 
          in: { last: "$$this", count: { $add: [
              "$$value.count", 
              { $cond: [ 
                  {$gt: [ { $subtract: [ "$$this", "$$value.last" ] }, 28800000 ] }, 
                  1, 
                  0 
              ] }
          ] } }
      } }
  } },
  { $project: { count: "$events.count" } }
])
```

It's gonna be slow on large dataset. In this case you may need to pre-aggregate counters at insert time.

Comment: This is awesome! Problem is we're running on 3.2, so I can't use addFields and reduce. I upgrade my mongo install on my development environment and tested it out, this method seems to produce the result needed. It's slow of course, it needs to run on a collection of around 20mil+ records, but that is not an issue as the result doesn't need to be realtime. This would be another reason I can add to push for a mongo upgrade in production. ;) Thanks!